# Rigid rotor: Allowed energies and their degeneracy

Tags: quantum-mechanics

*My main question is on (c) but I wrote out all parts for clarity*

A particle of mass $m$ is attached to a massless rod of length $l$ that is free to rotate but not translate.

(a) what is the Hamiltonian for such a system?

Here all the energy is kinetic so: $$KE=\frac{L^2}{2I}$$
Note: $$\vec{L}=\vec{r}\times\vec{p}=L\hat{z}$$

Thus, $$\hat{H}=\frac{\hat{L_z}^2}{2I} = \frac{\hbar^2}{2I}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\phi^2}$$

(b) What are the eigenfunctions of this system?

$$H\left|f\right>=\lambda\left|f\right>$$

Recall: $$L_z\left|f_l^m\right>=\hbar m\left|f_l^m\right>$$

The eigenfunctions are then spherical harmonics.

(c) What are the allowed energy levels of our system and what are the degeneracies of the energy levels? 
$$E_m=\hbar m$$ since this is our eigenvalue in the eigenvalue equation.

Since the eigenvalues are only degenerate for different values of $l$ there is no degeneracy when we fix our $l$ value.

I.e. for $l=n \implies m=-n,...,0,...,n$

And for $l’=n+1 \implies m=-(n+1),-n,...,0,...,n,(n+1)$

we see that the $m$ values can be the same  for each $l$ in $l’$ but. That only works for two separate $l$ values.

This whole part has me confused am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong here.

First, this equation:
$$\vec L = \vec r \times \vec p = \hat L_z$$

Where are all the other terms? From your statement oh the question, there seems to be no assumption that there can only be a $z$ component for angular momentum.

Then you go on to state that 
$$\hat H = \frac{\hat L_z}{2I} = \frac{\hbar^2}{2I} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial\phi^2}.$$

What's the reasoning behind the first step? The Hamiltonian represents the energy of a system. What's the energy supposed to be? (Hint: (1)) Also, 
$$\hat L_z \neq \hbar^2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial\phi^2},$$
so the second step needs to be fixed.

Sorry if I'm being a bit harsh here, but first you need to go and redo parts (a) and (b) before moving on because they are not correct. I'd love to help if you have any difficulties with these, but be sure to explain the reasoning behind the steps you take, and why you think they are correct.

Comment: So I edited the post a bit because you caught my typo: $$KE=\frac{L_z^2}{2I}=\frac{\hbar^2}{2I}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\phi^2}$$ since $$L_z=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}$$ I assumed that it was rotating in just the $xy$ plane and not rotating in any other direction so $\vec{L}=\vec{r}\times\vec{p}$ should pick out the component orthogonal to that which would mean $\vec{L}=L\hat{z}$ hence the choice of the $L_z$ operator. So if it can rotate in 3D I should have used the $L^2$ operator, is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track! Also, your first equation (you shouldn't use it, but I just wanted to let you know) is still missing a bit:  $L_z^2$ should have a negative sign in front of it.

Comment: Well $$L_z=-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}$$ so $$L_z^2=\left(-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}\right)^2=\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\phi^2}$$. Also the eigenfunctions should still be spherical harmonics right? just with different eigenvalues, namely $$\hbar^2 l(l+1)$$

Comment: what is $(-i)^2$? and yes, the eigenfunctions should be spherical harmonics. Whose eigenvalues are you referring to?

Comment: oh whoops, yup okay I see that mistake...

Comment: The eigenvalues I am referring to are that of $L^2$ so: $$L^2\left|f^m_l\right>=\hbar^2 l(l+1)\left|f_l^m\right>$$ where $f_l^m$ are our spherical harmonics.

Comment: Ok. You're ready for (c)! Be careful about expressing $\hat H$ in terms of $\hat L^2$.

Comment: Does this look correct?     A particle of mass $m$ is attached to a massless rod of length $l$ that is free to rotate but not translate.

(a) what is the Hamiltonian for such a system?

Here all the energy is kinetic so: $$KE=\frac{L^2}{2I}$$

Let $L^2$ be the operator $\hat{L^2}$ (from here on I will drop the hat)

Thus, $$\hat{H}=\frac{L^2}{2I} = \frac{-\hbar^2}{2I}\left(\frac{1}{sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(sin(\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\right)+\frac{1}{sin^2(\theta)}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\phi^2}\right)$$

Comment: (b) What are the Eigenfunctions of this system?

Recall: $$L^2\left|f_l^m\right>=\hbar^2 l(l+1) \left|f_l^m\right>$$ 

The Eigenfunctions are then spherical harmonics.

Multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{2I}$ to get the eigenvalue equation of the Hamiltonian (this will not change the Eigenfunction).

Comment: (c) What are the allowed energy levels of our system and what are the degeneracies of the energy levels?
$$E_l=\frac{\hbar^2}{2I}l(l+1)$$

This is our eigenvalue in the eigenvalue equation for the hamiltonian.

Notice for each value of $l$ there is $2l+1$ values for $m$, meaning for example if $l=1$ the states $\left|f_1^1\right>,\left|f_1^0\right>,\left|f_1^{-1}\right>$ all have the same energy of:$$\frac{\hbar^2}{2I}(2)=\frac{\hbar^2}{I}$$ How does that look? I think I fixed all of your comments (sorry for putting it into three separate comments!) ALSO THANKS FOR ALL YOUR HELP!!!

Comment: Yeah, this looks fine. Great job!